# PowerShell download and save wav file from API

Tags: powershell, wav

I am trying to download WAV files via a web API using PowerShell. The request succeeds, but when I write the content to a file using Out-File it will not play in windows media player. It shows like this (opened in text editor):

[image: wav_file1]

Whereas a sample wav file that does play, looks like this in text editor:

[image: wav_file2]

I am guessing it is some sort of encoding problem? But I don't know how to output to a wav file using proper encoding in PowerShell...

Here is my script, I am currently saving out a substring of "RawContent" to skip all the HTTP headers:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://developer.fuze.com/api/v1/call-recordings/recording-id/media').RawContent.Substring(488) | Out-File c:\stuff\recording.wav
```

Comment: A `WAV` file is not a text file. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1#description) _The Out-File cmdlet sends output to a file. It implicitly uses PowerShell's formatting system to write to the file. The file receives the same display representation as the terminal. This means that the output may not be ideal for programmatic processing **unless all input objects are strings**._

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` also has a parameter `-OutFile` which can save the wav file as-is to a file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a file in raw format. Then I converted it to wav using ffmpeg.
This is how I solved this problem:

```
 `$response = $client.PostAsync("https://tts.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/tts:synthesize", $con)
    $responseBytes = $response.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
    [io.file]::WriteAllBytes('.\test.raw',$responseBytes.Result)

    .\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i test.raw file.wav 2> $null
    
    $Player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer '.\file.wav'
    $Player.Play()
    
    Remove-Item .\test.raw
    Remove-Item .\file.wav`
```